# Define Mail Header in Pear PHP issue

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm trying to define Mail header like this :

```
From:Ahmed <ace.alik@gmail.com>
 Reply-To: ace.alik@gmail.com
```

This my php file :

```
$test = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '> ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];

...

$headers = array('From' => $test, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
```

But unfortunately this what I get when I send the mail:

```
From@mx.kangoulya.com:Ahmed <ace.alik@gmail.com>
```

So how to fix this issue please ?

Comment: That's a great example of how to let other people send spam from your server

Comment: @AD7six Sorry I'm newbie can you explain me more the Problem ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to build a full headers line with your `$test` var, and then treating it as if it was just a `From` line, e.g. you're essentially building

```
From: From: $_POST[name] <$_POST[email]>
etc..
```

Why not

```
$headers = array(
   'From' => $_POST['name'],
   'Reply-To' => $whatever,
   'To' => $whatever,
   etc...
)
```

Comment: Thank's this work's but how to avoid that my message goes to spam ?